# Cambiar ID con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mi pregunta es la siguiente.
Tengo dos etiquetas de audio en html, pero una tiene el id="player", al dar click a un botón quiero que el id cambie a la siguiente etiqueta. Tengo lo siguiente.

```
<audio id="player" data-value="dato">
<audio id="" data-value="segundodato">
<button id="boton" type="button">Siguiente</button
```

¿Aguién me podría ayudar a solucionarlo? No tengo nada en Jquery aún.

Comment: cual es la siguiente etiqueta?

Comment: La misma etiqueta <audio> pero sin id, quiero que al dar click, se elimine el id del que lo tenga y se asigne al siguiente.

Comment: sigo sin entender, se elimine el id del que lo tenga??? y se asigne al siguiente???

Answer (score 3):

Necesitas definir el campo del siguiente id de audio

```
<audio id="player" data-value="dato">
<audio id="player2" data-value="segundodato">
<button id="boton" type="button">Siguiente</button>

$("#boton").click(function(){
   $("#player").removeAttr("id");
   $("#player2").attr("id","player");
});
```

Como resultado:

```
<audio data-value="dato">
<audio id="player" data-value="segundodato">
<button id="boton" type="button">Siguiente</button>
```

Comment: Agregué más atributos con el segundo id, y hace bien los cambios. Tal como mostraste ;)